# Display first card as half from second slide in bxSlider

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I am using bxSlider to display a card carousel. My settings -

```
var carousel = {
    minSlides: 4.5,
    maxSlides: 4.5,
    slideWidth: 250,
    pager: false,
    moveSlides: 4,
    speed:2000,
    hideControlOnEnd:true
   }
```

Is there a way that on clicking 'next' I could display the first card as half, too?(without changing the width of the slider)

I am trying to change the value along x-axis as below but the slider stops working.

```
.slider{
    transform: translate3d(-900px, 0px, 0px) !important;
}
```

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT:** A simpler and direct approach to this was provided by 'Karan' and works perfectly. However, I want that this effect should apply only after the user clicks 'next' and not at first display of cards.

My code below -

```
function translate(){
  var current = carousel.getCurrentSlide();
  if(current>=1){
        $('div.slider')
        .css({'margin-left': '5.56%','margin-right': '5.56%' } );
        
    }
  
  
}
```

Calling this function on clicking next as-

```
onSlideAfter: function() {
         translate();
```

This works fine except that when I click previous and go back to the initial display, it again shows as half.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you share any fiddle of your demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add below css to your code. As you are displaying `4.5` slides each slide will get `22.22%` width from div. And you want to display `half` from `first` and `last` slides so you will need to `0.25%` `width` from `first` and `last` slides. So you can divide `22.22/4` and set `margin-left` and `margin-right`.

```
div.bxslider {
  margin-left: 5.56%;
  margin-right: 5.56%;
}
```

Try it below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    minSlides: 4.5,
    maxSlides: 4.5,
    slideWidth: 250,
    pager: false,
    moveSlides: 4,
    speed:2000,
    hideControlOnEnd:true
   });
});
```

```css
div.bxslider {
  margin-left: 5.56%;
  margin-right: 5.56%;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.css">

<div class="bxslider">
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x680/112233/ffffff?text=FooBar1" /></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x680/ee5678/ffffff?text=FooBar2" /></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x680/435ab6/ffffff?text=FooBar3" /></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x680/11cc22/ffffff?text=FooBar4" /></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x680/ffa500/ffffff?text=FooBar5" /></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x680/cc44ff/ffffff?text=FooBar6" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! worked perfectly ! This approach is simpler and direct. Although, I want that this effect should be applied only after the user clicks the next button.i.e. at first glance first card at first position will not be half. The card in the first position ONLY after sliding should display as half. I am editing my question and including the logic for it which is working except one small issue-which is in the description.

Answer (score 0):

Call a function on

```
    onSlideBefore: function () {
    translateprev();
    } //to undo the changes

    function translateprev() {
    var current = carousel.getCurrentSlide();
    if (current < 1) {
    console.log("IF")
    $('div.slider')
    .css({ 'margin-left': '', 'margin-right': '' });
    }
    }
```